# Why is my accuracy always 0.0000e+00, and loss and huge?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm pretty new to machine learning, and this is my first project using tensorflow and keras. I'm trying to predict a numerical value given a data set but my model is working.

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(dates, prices, test_size=0.33)


x_train = np.reshape(x_train,(x_train.shape[0], 1, x_train.shape[1]))
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(30, return_sequences=True, input_shape= (x_train.shape[0], 1)))
# model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(100,activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(1,activation='softmax'))


model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=5)
```

This is my model above, but whenever it runs it shows this below:

```
Epoch 1/5
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 1686, 1) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1686, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name='lstm_input'), name='lstm_input', description="created by layer 'lstm_input'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 1, 1).
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 1686, 1) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1686, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name='lstm_input'), name='lstm_input', description="created by layer 'lstm_input'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 1, 1).
53/53 [==============================] - 2s 2ms/step - loss: 1314.1159 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/5
53/53 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 1332.1348 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 3/5
53/53 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 1307.5851 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 4/5
53/53 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 1327.0625 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 5/5
53/53 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 1314.4220 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
<tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f1cdfc56668>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this and improve accuracy and loss?
Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: softmax won't go with 1 output neuron, at least 2

Comment: zero accuracy because loss doesn't converge (reduce)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to predict a numerical value then you are NOT doing a classification problem but rather a regression problem. Therefore your dense layer with 1 neuron should have no activation function.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your last layer of Sequential model with this:

```py
model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal'))
```

Regression task dont need softmax as activation function because softmax is mostly used in multi class classification